# Does Duktape has a Function for Executing an External Program in Linux?

Tags: javascript, duktape

I am using Duktape on Linux (Command Line, not Browser),
and would like my code to execute an external program in Linux, for example `ls`.

I went over Duktape's website, looking for Reference of the JavaScript functions supported by this Interpreter and Compiler,
but couldn't find any.

I did find there an API Reference, but that seems to be talking about calling functions that the Interpreter/Compiler library provides to outside callers,
and not the functions that are used inside a JavaScript program, that the Interpreter/Compiler runs..

Does any one know If there is a way to Execute an external program in Duktape in Linux,
and If yes, a 1-2 line sample code would be really helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duktape is a pure JS execution environment. It does only provide functionality as defined in specific JS versions (mostly ES5, some ES6 and very few ES7). See also the [Post ES5 status page](https://wiki.duktape.org/postes5features).

Accessing the file system or starting processes is not part of the JS language defintion. For that you have to provide your own environment, which implements such functionality for scripts.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike.  Regarding you last sentence: "For that you have to provide your own environment, which implements such functionality for scripts" - does it mean that the main program can still be written in JavaScript, and it will call something external? Or that the program has to completely be in a different programming language and not JS?

Comment: The own environment is a C/C++ host application which implements functionality that can be used by the embedded JS scripts. Browsers and Node.js implement such (but for Google's V8). See the [MySQL Workbench repo](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/tree/8.0/tools/mga/src/library) for a Node.js like implementation for duktape.

Comment: What you say is that  the C/C++ program will host (and load and execute) the guest JS program, using Duktape API, yet the Duktape JS program despite being a guest, will be able to call parts in the host program?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The host app has to define APIs usable by JS and provide the implementation for them (e.g. see the [filesystem access](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/tools/mga/src/library/filesystem.cpp#L594) API registration).

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much. BTW, there's another JavaScript interpreter that works on Linux Command Line, which is called QuickJS ( https://bellard.org/quickjs/ ). There, we have 2 options for running external programs/scripts: `std.popen()` and `os.exec()`. I am writing this here for peope who might get here from Google, looking for a JavaScript engine that can do it..

Comment: Tbh. I'm a bit confused now. You have an own JS engine which does what you want already and you ask a question here about duktape?

Comment: Yes, I am comparing the 2, and needed them both to have the basic feature of running an external program. QuickJS has it, yet did not know If it's possible with Duktape too. Since it doesn't, it means I will not be able to use it for my needs.